# Difference between "he drives a taxi" and "he is a taxi driver"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I wonder if the two following sentences have similar meaning and give you the same impression.

A: He drives a taxi.
B: He is a taxi driver.

Answer (score 3):

The first talks about what **kind of car** "he" drives. It states that "he" habitually/usually drives a taxi car. "He" may or may not be picking up passengers and making money.

Since **taxi driver** is a progression, like **bus driver** or **dog walker**, the second describes his **profession**.

Someone *could* be driving a taxi and not work as a taxi driver, and therefore it would not be wholly accurate to say that person is a taxi driver.